# Translating english statements to logical statement. Scope Ambiguity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working through Discrete Mathematics by Rosen and am in Section 1.6 Example 13. There are two statements made and translated as follow:

“A student in this class has not read the book" 
“Everyone in this class passed the first exam”

which are rewritten in logical statements as :\

Let C(x) be “x is in this class,” B(x) be “x has read the nook,” and P (x) be “x passed the first exam.” The remises are ∃x(C(x) ∧ ¬B(x)) and ∀x(C(x) → P (x)).

My question is why is the first statement a conjunction and the second one a conclusion ? Is this just scope ambiguity or did I miss anything obvious ?

Comment: Well, the first is about one student.  The second is about all students.  Any statement about a single being is just an observation about a single being.  Any statement about a universal is implicitely stating if anything one thing is in the universal group then that one thing fits the descriptor (because *every* thing in the universal group fits the descriptor).  So it is valid to translate $\forall(x$ so that $C(x))P(x)$ as $\forall x(C(x)\to P(x))$.  Obviously you can't so that for a single instance (as a single instance says nothing about other instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, consider the alternatives.

Suppose we use a conditional for that first statement:

$$\exists x (C(x) \to \neg B(x))$$

Notice that this statement would be true simply by pointing to anything that is not a student in the class, because for such an object, $C(x)$ would be false, and hence the whole conditional would be true. And so, given the existence of any such object, the whole existential statement would be true ... even though it ends up saying nothing about any actual students that are in the course, and whether they read the book or not. So, this is clearly not what we want!

What we want, is that there is something that is a student *and* hasn't read the book, hence the conjunction.

OK, but why doesn't this work for the second statement?  Well, consider we use a conjunction there:

$$\forall x (C(x) \land P(x))$$

Notice that this statement means that all objects in the domain are students that are in the class, and have passed the first test. But wait: why would everyone in the domain have to be a student in the class?  Maybe we want the domain to also include other objects, like the teacher. So, what we want to say is that *if* you are a student in the class, *then* you passed the first test. Hence the conditional.

So yes, *often* (though not always!) existentials are combined with conjunctions, and universals with conditionals.  And this has nothing to do with the scope of the quantifier.